# Best Postfix spam RBL policy weight daemon?

Tags: debian, postfix, spam, rbl

I just heard about [policyd-weight](http://www.policyd-weight.org/) so I did an `apt-cache search policyd` which returns three options:

- [policyd-weight](http://www.policyd-weight.org/)
- [postfix-policyd](http://www.policyd.org/tiki-index.php)
- [postfwd](http://www.postfwd.org/)

Which one is the best, and do you have any tips on setting them up?

Our current setup is whitelister plus postgrey to greylist RBLd hosts, then fail2ban them for 10 minutes if they have 10 failures, followed by content filtering (Kaspersky Anti-Spam). The content filtering is pretty good, but there's still a lot of spam that gets through the RBL greylisting.

Answer (score 6):

I'm very happy with policyd-weight. I run it on several mail servers and I would guess that it stops a good 80%-90% of spammy attempts straight away.

Answer (score 0):

My current setup uses policyd (without -weight), I'm happy with it on some postfix boxes with low traffic (50k hits to policyd a day which boils down to ~ 3k mails getting through).

policyd-weight wasn't there at the time so I can't say if it is better or not.

I'd also add:

- [postgrey](http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/) and its variant [taRgrey](http://k2net.hakuba.jp/targrey/index.en.html) (they use BDB files instead of SQL, could be good if you don't have separate hardware for the database to remove the db server overhead)
- [gld](http://www.gasmi.net/gld.html) - never tried it, I don't know anything about it other than it [tends to grow big databases](http://www.irbs.net/internet/postfix/0607/2065.html)